# Pandas could not be able to read given CSV file correctly

Tags: python, pandas

I tried below code but could not be able to correct dataframe. Please let me know the correct code to read CSV file using pandas.

CSV file:[CSV File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cxnRl9Jz7RTWg5hddZdT7eLExs5dq_Cf/view)

My Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv("Data 8199 2391 6_6_2019 13_39_02.csv",sep="\r\t",skiprows=68,encoding = "ISO-8859-1",index_col=0)
df.head()
```

Not satisfied Output:
[image]

Comment: How's your data looks like?

Comment: While asking the question prefer not to post images instead include your actual code.

Comment: Update all your concerned aread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("Data 8199 2391 6_6_2019 13_39_02.csv", delimiter="\t", skiprows=68,
                 encoding="utf-16", index_col=0)
print(df.head())
```

**Output:**

```
                        Time  101 <RoomTemperature> (C)  ...  319 <DU5> (C)  320 (C)
Scan                                                      ...                        
1     06-06-2019 13:39:02:392                     21.170  ...         49.767   42.857
2     06-06-2019 13:39:32:376                     21.138  ...         49.944   43.253
3     06-06-2019 13:40:02:376                     21.116  ...         50.095   43.675
4     06-06-2019 13:40:32:376                     21.215  ...         50.227   44.085
5     06-06-2019 13:41:02:376                     21.234  ...         50.385   44.561
```

Comment: Not working getting "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: As per your question the given answer should read `csv` file properly.

Comment: Gettin Error @ df = pd.read_csv("Data 8199 2391 6_6_2019 13_39_02.csv", delimiter="\t", skiprows=68,
                 encoding="ISO-8859-1", index_col=0)

Comment: I think there is a problem with your encoding technique.

Comment: I suggest that you try `utf-16` encoding.